# No custom ConversionExecutor found with id 'shortDate'

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I have defined a custom converter for converting a date String to a java.sql.Date object when transiting state in a java spring webflow. However I am getting the error below when submitting the form.

Can you help me understand why am I getting this error?

I am using 4.1.5.RELEASE spring framework 2.4.2.RELEASE spring webflow.

**Converter:**

```
import org.springframework.binding.convert.converters.StringToObject;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.sql.Date;

public class StringToDateTwoWayConverter extends StringToObject {
    private DateFormat formatter = null;

    public StringToDateTwoWayConverter () {
        super(StringToDateTwoWayConverter.class);
        formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    }

    @Override
    protected Object toObject(String string, Class targetClass) throws Exception {
        Date date = null;
        try {
            long parsedDate = formatter.parse(string).getTime();
            date = new Date(parsedDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return date;
    }

    @Override
    protected String toString(Object object) throws Exception {
        Date date = (Date) object;
        return formatter.format(date);
    }
}
```

**conversionService:**

```
import com.housemanagement.converter.StringToDateTwoWayConverter;
import org.springframework.binding.convert.service.DefaultConversionService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("conversionService")
public class ApplicationConversionService extends DefaultConversionService
{
    @Override
    protected void addDefaultConverters() {
        super.addDefaultConverters();        
        this.addConverter(new StringToDateTwoWayConverter());
        this.addConverter("shortDate", new StringToDateTwoWayConverter());
    }

}
```

**webflow-config.xml**

```
<flow:flow-builder-services id="flowBuilderServices" view-factory-creator="mvcViewFactoryCreator" conversion-service="conversionService" />
```

**Form binding**

```
<binding property="dob" converter="shortDate" required="true" />
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[dispatcher]: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
org.springframework.binding.convert.ConversionExecutorNotFoundException: No custom ConversionExecutor found with id 'shortDate' for converting from sourceClass [java.lang.String] to targetClass [java.sql.Date]
    at org.springframework.binding.convert.service.GenericConversionService.getConversionExecutor(GenericConversionService.java:181)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.support.FlowBuilderContextImpl$ParentConversionServiceProxy.getConversionExecutor(FlowBuilderContextImpl.java:159)
    at org.springframework.binding.convert.service.GenericConversionService.getConversionExecutor(GenericConversionService.java:179)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.AbstractMvcView.addMapping(AbstractMvcView.java:444)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.AbstractMvcView.addModelBindings(AbstractMvcView.java:409)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.AbstractMvcView.bind(AbstractMvcView.java:387)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.AbstractMvcView.processUserEvent(AbstractMvcView.java:225)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.handleEvent(ViewState.java:225)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:195)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:537)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:259)
    at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:228)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to call super with the type you want to register:

```
public StringToDateTwoWayConverter () {
    super(Date.class);
    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
}
```

Comment: are you sure you recompiled everything before re-trying?

Comment: Yes, I have cleaned and built the entire project. However I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Are you sure you you want to be dealing with java.sql.Date instead of java.util.Date?

Comment: try adding <property name="useSpringBeanBinding" value="true" /> to your mvcViewFactoryCreator